# SQL Query matching table 1 to table 2

Tags: sql, matching

I have two tables JOB and EMP; values are like this

```
CREATE TABLE JOB (JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,JOBNAME CHAR(15));
CREATE TABLE EMP(EMPID SMALLINT, JOBID SMALLINT, SAL SMALLINT, CITYID SMALLINT);

INSERT INTO JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) VALUES
        ( 1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
        (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
        (3,'TESTING'),
        (4,'TESTING'),
        (7,'TESTING'),
        (9,'RESEARCH'),
        (8,'HR');

INSERT INTO EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL,CITYID) VALUES
   (  100,1,1000,10),
   (  200,2,2000,10),
   (  300,1,2500,20),
   (  400,3,1000,10),
   (  500,6,3000,10),
   (  600,8,1000,30),
   (  700,8,2000,10)
;
```

I want to display all jobname count and avg salaries; for the jobname if jobid's not exists then display 0

For the given cityid's ( Emp table), take all jobids for each jobname (from job table ) and match in Emp table, if exists display count (count of jobids present in Emp table) and avgsal else 0 for count and avgsal.  result should be in the order of job names present in job table. Output should be like this

```
Cityid  jobname        count avg-sal
10       development    2     1500
10       TESTING        1     1000
10       RESEARCH       0      0
10       HR             1      2000
total                   4      1500
20      development     1      2500
20      Testing         0      0
20      Research        0      0
20      HR              0      0
Total                   1     2500
Grand Total             5    1700
```

I tried thru joins, but didnt work properly; Is it better use joins or Cursor ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select 10 as cityid, jobname, count(e.empid) as cnt,
       avg(e.sal)
from jobname j left join
     emp e
     on e.jobid = j.jobid and e.cityid = 10
group by grouping sets (jobname), () );
```

Comment: Result for the query is like like this 
10 DEVELOPMENT     2 1500
10 HR              1 2000
10 RESEARCH        0 NULL
10 TESTING         1 1000

Jobnames are not in the order of table values. and totals are not displayed.

if I want to display data for cityid 10 and 20, if add 20 also to cityid, and in groupingsets, its not displaying cityids and results are not as expected..